# How To a DOM Flush When Page is Changed

Tags: next.js

I honestly don't know how to word this in React-ese, so I will use very basic English.

I have a NextJS page that has an ad unit from a vendor we work with it's the only page with this unit. An external JS script loads the ad unit on the page component. The js script is manipulating the DOM, adding elements to the head and body tags. The script is loaded only on one page.

The problem occurs when a user navigates from page to page, the DOM manipulations remain on the DOM after they've long left. I'm trying both  tags as well as building the script tag with Vanilla js and adding it to the DOM through useEffect.

Help, I keep trying different things and none of them work.

I tried doing a reload on unmount.

I tried plucking the elements out on unmount. Doesn't work cuz the element attributes are dynamically generated (I'm assuming to evade adblockers).

shallow false router.push

many more trials and errors...

Comment: Have you tried the NextJS `<Script />` component?

Comment: @grantmx yes I have

Comment: You can try forcing hard navigation all the links on the page which has unwanted scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code examples to go from, if you add a `key={}` prop to the component or parent component in question with say...the slug of the new page React be forced to rerender the DOM.